# Is there a delay after retagging before synonyms can be proposed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

On the [parallel-programming](/questions/tagged/parallel-programming) tag, I would like to suggest the synonyms [parallel](/questions/tagged/parallel) and [parallel-processing](/questions/tagged/parallel-processing). Initially I couldn't do so because my score was less than 5 in the tag. 20 minutes ago I dutifully acquired the score by adding the tag to a (valid) [parallel programming question I'd answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902136/advice-on-starting-a-large-multi-threaded-programming-project/1902861) in the past.

I'm still not allowed to propose any synonyms, but my user page correctly reports my score as 18 in this tag.

Is there a built-in delay after retagging, before synonyms are allowed (perhaps to prevent synonym spamming)? If so, how long is the delay?

Or am I missing something else obvious?